# Use find and do command on filename without "./" prefix

Tags: linux, command-line, bash, find, string-manipulation

Performing a `cp` on filenames in multiple subdirectories and prefix them with `foo-` leads to an error:

```
$ find my-dir -path "*/*" -execdir sh -c 'cp {} foo-{}' \;
cannot create regular file ‘foo-./blabla.jpg’: No such file or directory
```

On macOS I don't get this `./` prefix and the command works fine.

Is there a way to `cp` the filename without the `./` prefix?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Even if elsewhere your command works fine, it's still flawed. [Never embed `{}` in the shell code](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/156010/108618).

The right approach is:

```
find my-dir -path "*/*" -execdir sh -c 'cp -- "$1" "foo-${1#./}"' sh {} \;
```

where `${1#./}` is responsible for removing the leading `./` (if any). Note I used [double dash](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/11376/108618), which is unnecessary (yet harmless) when `find` generates names with the `./` prefix, but useful otherwise.

Notes:

- The command doesn't check if the matching `whatever` is a file. You will get a warning from `cp` if it's a directory.
- The command doesn't check if `foo-whatever` exists and what it is. If it exists then you will get different results depending on whether it's a file or directory; and depending on if it's processed before or after `whatever`.