# In bash, how can I list only files?

Tags: linux, bash, unix

I'm looking to list only files and directories and no extra data.  It's used for parsing the data and I don't need the extra items of file size, permissions...etc.

TIA

Answer (score 2):

> It's used for parsing the data

#### Parsing – but how?

If you're parsing in a shell like this:

```sh
# don't
for f in $(dir); do my_parser "$f"; done
```

then this is [Bash pitfall number one](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashPitfalls#for_f_in_.24.28ls_.2A.mp3.29). In such case use `for f in ./*; do …`.

From now on I assume you're parsing by piping, like this: `dir | my_parser`.

---

#### Do not parse the output of `ls`/`dir`

Your `dir` (from [your answer](https://superuser.com/a/1626644/432690)) is probably [just `ls -C -b`](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/50379/108618). As [you shouldn't parse the output of `ls`](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs), you shouldn't parse the output of `dir` either.

---

#### You can parse the output of `find`

You can pipe `find` to a parser. Pathnames containing newlines will be misinterpreted while parsing. To parse reliably use GNU `find` with `-print0`. This will terminate each pathname with a null character (instead of a newline character). Pathnames themselves cannot contain null characters, so there will be no ambiguity. POSIX solution is `-exec printf '%s\0' {} +`. Purely POSIX tools usually expect text files as input and they [may not accept null characters](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap03.html#tag_03_403), but if your parser can accept null-terminated strings then this is how you can generate them from `find` that doesn't support `-print0`.

`find` descends to subdirectories by default. With GNU `find` you can change this by specifying `-maxdepth 1`. A solution for POSIX find is here: [*Limit POSIX find to specific depth*](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/330372/108618). If the starting point is `.` then the solution is `\( -name . -o -prune \)`.

`find starting_directory` prints `starting_directory` as the first pathname. I guess you'd like not to get this particular pathname. The relevant test is `! -path starting_directory` (remember `-path` treats its argument as a pattern). If starting directory is specified as `.` then `! -name .` will be enough. With GNU `find` `-mindepth 1` is an alternative, it will work regardless of the starting directory.

The final command can be one of the following:

```
find . -maxdepth 1 -mindepth 1                     # newline-terminated, GNU
find . \( -name . -o -prune \) ! -name .           # newline-terminated, POSIX
find . ! -name . -prune                            # newline-terminated, POSIX, simplified
find . -maxdepth 1 -mindepth 1 -print0             # null-terminated, GNU
find . ! -name . -prune -exec printf '%s\0' {} +   # null-terminated, POSIX
```

The list is not exhaustive, other equivalent forms exist.

All the above commands generate output where pathnames start with `./` (at least with `find` implementations I tested, but [apparently YMMV](https://superuser.com/q/1480324/432690)). You can remove this prefix by piping to `sed 's|^\./||'` (when newline-terminated) or to `sed -z 's|^\./||'` (when null-terminated; note `-z` is supported by GNU `sed` but it's not required by POSIX). E.g. like this:

```
find . ! -name . -prune | sed 's|^\./||'
```

Keep in mind that any solution using newline-terminated pathnames will fail or misbehave if some pathname contains a newline character.

---

#### Maybe you don't even need `find`

If your parser is written by you in some programming language then you should use whatever way of listing files the language provides instead of relying on standalone executables like `ls`, `dir` or `find`. There should be a totally reliable way to iterate over directory entries.

Answer (score 1):

n/m.. found it.  Solution: dir

Answer (score 0):

As you've noticed, `dir` is a good option that by default is set up to do what you want, but the equivalent command for `ls` - which, being the more common tool, is probably more widely available on Unix-like systems - is `ls -1` (that's the number 1, not a lowercase L).

From `man ls`:

```
-1     list one file per line.
```